# Cannot retrieve Session value

Tags: asp.net, session

I've written a simple code to keep a USerID with the help of session. However I can't get Session value although it's not null. I've done exactly the way microsoft official tutorial says. Here's the code:

The code on the Default.aspx

```
string regCode = loginBase.getRegCodePerUser(txtLogin.Text);
Session["regCode"] = regCode;
//lblInfo.text=(string)Session["regCode"];When I check it shows the right string.It's OK
Response.Redirect("Selection.aspx");
```

I do not directly go to that page.I first go to Selection.aspx, then UpdateStages.

And this is the code on the other page(UpdateStages.apsx):

```
       if ((string)Session["connSTR"] == null && (string)Session["user"] == null)
    {
        Response.Redirect("Default.aspx");
    }
    else if ((string)Session["regCode"]!=null)
    {
        regCode=(string)Session["regCode"];
        lblInfo.Text = regCode;//Show nothing. Empty.           
    }
```

Comment: I think you should provide more details

Comment: Nothing seems to be wrong in the provided code.

Comment: I can't see anything wrong, as a proof of concept try  Session["regCode"] = "testString"; instead of loginBase.getRegCodePerUser(txtLogin.Text);

Comment: What is `getRegCodePerUser` doing?  I think you need to provide the implementation to that in order to get an answer.   Also, when are you setting `Session` during the page lifecycle, and when are you trying to retrieve it?

Comment: Yes, I guess I found it. But it's very weird. So I did as TBohenen said. That worked. But isn't this too bad?

Answer (score 1):

It might very well be that when you set the session variable:

```
Session["regCode"] = loginBase.getRegCodePerUser(txtLogin.Text);
```

That the username is not available yet and that is why it's returning an empty string, and I would assume that you are executing this code: `lblStatus.Text =loginBase.getRegCodePerUser(txtLogin.Text);` on a different page/after the user has logged in and that is why you get the value in the label when you assign it directly.

Put a breakpoint on where you set the Session variable and see if the value is being set.

Otherwise your session settings could be incorrect in your web.config which causes the session values to be cleared before you get to your second page where you are accessing it.

Comment: Have you tried putting a breakpoint on where you set the value and where you retrieve it? Also, is it on the same page but different post backs?

Comment: Where I assign value to Session["regCode"] I cold fix it by directly assigning a value to it. But on another page where I compare Session["regCode"] with another string I get again same thing.Can my Session exprire  earlier than it should?

Comment: OK,I see it'll take tons of time so I thought what if I use a static variable?Would it do the job?

Comment: No, You will have to figure out what is wrong with your session, Static variables won't work because once the Request is completed, the static variable does not exist anymore.

Comment: have you made any changes to you web.config?

Comment: No I have not made any changes to it.Maybe I don't know but do I have to somehow initialize the session declared in the default page? I mean in the Default page I say Session["regCode"]=regCode;Then I redirect to another page. Is the Session still supposed to be alive? and, when I check if ((string)Session["regCode"]!=null) I get false which indicates that it's not null.It just returns empty string when I want to retrieve it.

Comment: Ok, well the fact that the string is empty means that it is assigned an empty value if infact intially it's assigned the username and the session is kept alive. There are so many things that might go wrong, the easiest will be to give us more code so that we can see if anything stands out. ie the relevant code from the first page as well as the second (including the method names etc.)